# How to use compile_flags.txt for C++ programming and suppress C++ related issues for development in C?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-warnings, clangd

Recently I wanted to use a compile_flags.txt-file to allow development in `C++20`. Clangd shows annoying warnings when using structured-bindings and C++-related features and so I created this file.
My `compile_flags.txt`-file looks like this:

> -std=c++20

When I want to edit a C-file however, clangd complains for the basic include directive: `#include <stdio.h>`:

```
clang[drv_argument_not_allowed_with]: Invalid argument '-std=c++20' not allowed with 'C'.
```

Naturally, I removed the `compile_flags.txt`-file and it works fine.
How can I achieve writing C++20-code and C-code at the same time without manually removing the file every time I decide to switch between the two? Thanks for any help in advance :^)

Comment: Have your build system write a `compile_commands.json` with the correct flags for each file. `compile_flags.txt` assumes that each file is compiled in the same way.

Comment: @user17732522 Oh ok. Could you provide an example (maybe as an answer) on how such a file might look like?

Comment: You shouldn't need to write it yourself. Your build system should do it for you. But you didn't mention what build system you are using. All the details, including a link to the specification of the `compile_commands.json` file can be found in the documentation for clangd: https://clangd.llvm.org/installation.html

Comment: @user17732522 At the moment I don't use a build system at all. That's why I didn't specify one. But if it's in the documentation, I guess I will use CMake to generate it for me and see what it does.

Comment: @user17732522 I generated the file just now and my conclusion is: I need to use a build system for it to work correctly. Is that necessarily the case? Or does a workaround exist somehow?

Comment: I question how you manage to develop with multiple files and different compiler invocations without any kind of build system. You should at least have something as simply as a shell script or Makefile. As the linked documentation mentions, you can then usually use `bear` (regardless of the details of the build system) to generate the database. If you are using some editor/IDE plugin for clangd, it may also support specifying the flags (again, see linked doc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to use a `compile_commands.json` file, another mechanism for providing flags to clangd that is more flexible than `compile_flags.txt` is a [clangd config file](https://clangd.llvm.org/config.html).

Clangd config files can specify [compiler flags to be added](https://clangd.llvm.org/config.html#add), and you can limit your configuration to only files whose path [matches a certain pattern](https://clangd.llvm.org/config.html#pathmatch) (for example, files with a certain extension). This allows specifying different configuration for different languages based on the file extension.

Here is an example of a config file that specifies that the flag `-std=c++20` should be added for `.cpp` files, and the flag `-std=c17` should be added for `.c` files:

```yaml
If:
  PathMatch: .*\.cpp

CompileFlags:
  Add: [-std=c++20]

---

If:
  PathMatch: .*\.c

CompileFlags:
  Add: [-std=c17]
```

This would go into a file named `.clangd` in your project's root directory.