# Config default C/C++ standard in VSCode with clangd and FQ bugs

Tags: vscode-extensions, clangd

Since I have struggled these warnings/errors for so long. I decided to ask this question and answer myself for late comers.

Extension: [vscode-clangd](https://github.com/clangd/vscode-clangd)

1. `'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extensionclang(-Wc++11-extensions)` or any "grammar belong to C++11 or later" error. How to **set default C/C++ standard** in vscode-clangd?
2. `Invalid argument '-std=c99' not allowed with 'Objective-C++'` or any  header extension .h interpreted as C/C++ conflicting with your standard. How to deal with this annoying bugs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Solutions

1. Three ways

   - For small projects: write a `compile_flags.txt`:

   ```
   -std=c++11
   ```

   - For big projects: generate `complie_commands.json` by a build system like CMake, which can be enabled by adding this to your CMakeLists.txt file:

   ```
   set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
   ```

   - If no compilation database(`compile_flags.txt`/`complie_commands.json`) is found, you can do this in your vscode:

     - `cmd/ctrl + shift + p`: Preferences: Open User Settings （JSON）
     - Add these into your `settings.json` file:

     ```json
     "clangd.fallbackFlags": [
         "-std=c++11",
         // do not add line below or it will cause conflict
         // "-std=c99",
       ],
     ```

     - `cmd/ctrl + shift + p`: clangd: Restart language server
2. You just can't set C & C++ standard into your `clangd.fallbackFlags` at the same time or it will conflict with each other. Two way to fix this:

   - But you can make your compiler treat your .h as C/C++ by `-x`

   ```bash
   > man clang

   -x <language>
            Treat subsequent input files as having type language.
   ```

   > see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19413311/17001641

   - or add a `.clangd` into your project root with these lines:

   ```
   If:
     PathMatch: .*\.cpp

   CompileFlags:
     Add: [-std=c++20]

   ---

   If:
     PathMatch: .*\.c

   CompileFlags:
     Add: [-std=c99]
   ```

   > see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76286667/17001641

##### Explaination

clangd first check for a [compilation database](https://clangd.llvm.org/design/compile-commands#compilation-databases) in the directory containing the source file, and then walk up into parent directories until we find one. The compilation database can be:

1. a file named `compile_commands.json` listing commands for **each** file. Usually generated by a build system like CMake.

   - Tedious and **error-prone** to write by hand
   - See: [format and example](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html#format)
2. a file named `compile_flags.txt` listing flags to be used for **all** files. Typically hand-authored for simple projects.

   - easy to use in small projects
3. If no compilation database is found, use `clangd.fallbackFlags`.